# Can I visit the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, borders

I was charged with some drug offences years ago, and they were all dropped because I was just a passenger and didn't know it was happening. I am not a drug trafficker, nor do I do drugs. I met someone online and decided to go to his province with him on that weekend, not knowing he was taking drugs (pot) in his trunk.  All charges were dropped. Just bad luck for me that the 2 people I met online both did the same thing. I just wanted to move to Ontario and was hoping to meet someone there to do that. Before those two guys, I had no criminal record! As far as I know all charges were expunged here in Canada. But I have a friend in the US ( enchanted Hills) like I would love to visit as his health has deteriorated some. I would be visiting no longer than 10 days. My question is can I get into the States to visit? Last time I was there was in 1995 when I went to the Sturgis Bike Rally.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Answer (score 8):

Merely having been arrested or charged with a crime is not enough to bar you from entering the US, though you might be asked about it at the border.

In order to be inadmissible, you would have to have been convicted.

The CBP states these are the [reasons one might be found inadmissible](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1769/~/waiver-of-inadmissibility---applying-for-advance-permission-to-enter-the-u.s.), in general:

> - If you have a communicable disease,
> - Determined to be a drug abuser or addict,
> - If you have a criminal record of multiple convictions,
> - If you have a criminal record for crimes of moral turpitude,
> - Violated any law or regulation relating to a controlled substance including but not limited to trafficking in a controlled substance,
> - If you have trafficked in persons,
> - If you have been involved in money laundering,
> - If you have overstayed a previous period of admission to the United States

Comment: "In order to be inadmissible, you would have to have been convicted." Or if you admit to the crime even if you weren't convicted.